# Question on independence of multivariate Gaussian under orthogonal projections onto subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, independence

Consider $X:=(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ multivariate Gaussian distribution, i.e. $X \sim \mathcal{N}_{n}(\mu, \Sigma).$

Now let

$P_{E_{1}}$ and $P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $E_{1}$ and its orthogonal complement $E_{1}^{\perp}$, respectively.

Is it true that $P_{E_{1}}X$ and $P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}X$ are independent?

My idea:

Consider the matrix $$\overline{P}:=\begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}X\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}X\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot X$$

As a linear transformation of multivariate Gaussian, it is once again multivariate Gaussian and its distribution is given as

$$ \overline{P} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \mu, \begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \Sigma\cdot \begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}^{T}\right),$$

and  in our case to get independence, we are only interested in the expression

$$\begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \Sigma\cdot \begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}^{T}=\begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}\\ P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \Sigma\cdot \begin{pmatrix} P_{E_{1}}^{T}&& P_{E_{1}^{\perp}}^{T}\end{pmatrix}$$

But I am not sure whether this expression will help me get to independence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has standard normal distribution then $(X,X)$ has  a bivariate normal disrtribution. Its projectios to the coordinate axes are both equal to $X$ so they are not independent.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am giving counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you call it $E_1$ rather than just $E$ when it's not distinguished from anything called $E_2.$

**Jointly** Gaussian random vectors are independent if they are uncorrelated. (And of course, not otherwise. That would be true regardless of whether they are Gaussian and regardless of whether they are *jointly* Gaussian.)

If $U\in\mathbb R^k$ and $V\in\mathbb R^\ell$ are random vectors with expected values $\mu\in\mathbb R^k$ and $\nu\in\mathbb R^\ell,$ then we define
$$
\operatorname{cov}(U,V) = \operatorname E\left( (U-\mu)(V-\nu)^\top \right) \in \mathbb R^{k\times\ell}.
$$
That this covariance is $0$ is what it means to say $U,V$ are uncorrelated.

Next we have
$$
\operatorname{cov}\left( P_{E_1}X, P_{E_1^\bot}X \right) = P_{E_1} \Big( \operatorname{cov}(X,X)\Big) P_{E_1^\bot}^\top = P_{E_1}\Sigma P_{E_1^\bot}^\top = P_{E_1}\Sigma P_{E_1^\bot}
$$
(where the last equality is because orthogonal projection matrices are symmetric).

That last matrix is zero only if every column of $\Sigma$ is orthogonal either to $E_1$ or to $E_1^\bot.$ Under the cirumstances, that means every column is a member of either $E_1^\bot$ or $E_1.$